# Bad positioning of tables in beamer presentation

Tags: tables, beamer

I created these slides:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usetheme{quito-light}
\usepackage{booktabs} %tables
\usepackage{siunitx} %units, numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[space]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\frame{{Table of contents}\tableofcontents}

% SECTION 1
\begin{section}{Characteristics of atmospheric motion}
    % FRAME 1
    \begin{frame}{FRAME 1}
        \scriptsize
        \begin{table}
            \captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
            \begin{+array}{colspec={Q[wd=0.566\linewidth]},delimiter={right=\rbrace,left=.}}
                \caption{Characteristics of motion}
                \vspace{-1ex}
                \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                    Earth's radius&a\sim\qty{e6}{m}\\
                    Earth's rotation rate&\Omega\sim\qty{e-4}{s^{-1}}\\
                    Acceleration of gravity&g\sim\qty{9,81}{m.s^{-2}}\\
                    Sea-level pressure&p\textsubscript{ref}\sim\qty{e5}{kg.m^{-1}.s^{-2}}\\
                    H\textsubscript{2}O freezing temperature &T\textsubscript{ref}\sim\qty{273}{K}\\
                    \begin{+array}{colspec={@{} l}, rowsep=1pt, delimiter={left=.,right=\rbrace}}
                    {Equator-pole (tropospheric vertical)\\
                    potential temperature difference}
                    \end{+array}
                    &\triangle\Theta\sim\qty{40}{K}\\
                    Dry gas constant&R=\qty{287}{m^2.s^{-2}.K}\\
                    Dry isentropic exponent&\gamma\sim\qty{1,4}{}\\ 
                \end{tblr}\\[-1ex]
                \begin{+array}
                    \caption{Auxiliary quantities}
                    \vspace{-1ex}
                    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                        Sea-level air density&\rho\textsubscript{ref}=\frac{p\textsubscript{ref}}{RT\textsubscript{ref}}\sim\qty{1,25}{kg.m^{-3}}\\
                        Density scale height&h\textsubscript{sc}=\frac{\gamma p\textsubscript{ref}}{g \rho\textsubscript{ref}}\sim\qty{11}{km}\\
                        Sound speed&c\textsubscript{ref}=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma p\textsubscript{ref}}{\rho\textsubscript{ref}}}\sim\qty{330}{m.s^{-1}}\\
                        Internal wave speed&c\textsubscript{int}=\sqrt{gh\textsubscript{sc}\frac{\triangle\Theta}{T\textsubscript{ref}}}\sim\qty{110}{m.s^{-1}}\\
                        Thermal wind velocity&u\textsubscript{ref}=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{gh_{sc}}{\Omega a}\frac{\triangle\Theta}{T\textsubscript{ref}}\sim\qty{12}{m.s^{-1}}\\
                    \end{tblr}  
                \end{+array}
            \end{+array}
                \qquad
                \begin{minipage}{0.342\linewidth}
                    \caption{Physically distinguished scales}
                    \vspace{-1ex}
                    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                        Planetary scale&L\textsubscript{p}=\frac{\pi}{2}{a}\sim\qty{10000}{km}\\
                        Obukhov radius&L\textsubscript{Ob}=\frac{c\textsubscript{ref}}{\Omega}\sim\qty{3300}{km}\\
                        Synoptic scale&L\textsubscript{Ro}=\frac{c\textsubscript{int}}{\Omega}\sim\qty{1100}{km}\\
                        Meso-$\beta$ scale&L\textsubscript{Meso}\frac{u\textsubscript{ref}}{\Omega}\sim\qty{150}{km}\\
                        Meso-$\gamma$ scale&h\textsubscript{sc}=\frac{\gamma p\textsubscript{ref}}{g \rho\textsubscript{ref}}\sim\qty{11}{km}\\
                    \end{tblr} 
                \end{minipage}              
        \end{table}
    \end{frame} 
\end{section}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the tables are not positioned correctly. I can't seem to find my mistake.
Could you eventually help?

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot, so at least me can "see" your problem? Thank you

Comment: As said before: if you use a custom theme which is not included in the commonly used tex distributions, either check if you can reproduce your problem without it and remove it or if it is essential to your question, include it in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- a section is not an environment. Write `\section{section name}` at the start. That's all you need to do with sections
- the syntax `\frame{{frametitle} content}` is really weird. Don't get into the habit of using this. I know this comes from the example of your theme, but at best this works by accident.
- The syntax for `+array` is `\begin{+array}{<settings>} <content> \end{+array}`. In the `+array` around your second tabular, the `{}` for the settings is missing. This will cause an error. You could either add it, or just remove the whole environment, it does not make a lot of sense there.
- are you sure it is a good idea to squeeze so much content on a single slide. Even with your `\scriptsize`, there was not enough room on the frame to fit both tables above each other, I had to reduce the font even further. I'm not convinced the audience will be able to even read text so small.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usetheme{quito-light}
\usepackage{booktabs} %tables
\usepackage{siunitx} %units, numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[space]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

% SECTION 1
\section{Characteristics of atmospheric motion}
    % FRAME 1
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{FRAME 1}
        \tiny
        \begin{table}
            \captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
            \begin{+array}{colspec={Q[wd=0.568\linewidth]},delimiter={right=\rbrace,left=.}}
                \caption{Characteristics of motion}
                \vspace{-1ex}
                \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                    Earth's radius&a\sim\qty{e6}{m}\\
                    Earth's rotation rate&\Omega\sim\qty{e-4}{s^{-1}}\\
                    Acceleration of gravity&g\sim\qty{9,81}{m.s^{-2}}\\
                    Sea-level pressure&p\textsubscript{ref}\sim\qty{e5}{kg.m^{-1}.s^{-2}}\\
                    H\textsubscript{2}O freezing temperature &T\textsubscript{ref}\sim\qty{273}{K}\\
                    \begin{+array}{colspec={@{} l}, rowsep=1pt, delimiter={left=.,right=\rbrace}}
                    {Equator-pole (tropospheric vertical)\\
                    potential temperature difference}
                    \end{+array}
                    &\triangle\Theta\sim\qty{40}{K}\\
                    Dry gas constant&R=\qty{287}{m^2.s^{-2}.K}\\
                    Dry isentropic exponent&\gamma\sim\qty{1,4}{}\\ 
                \end{tblr}\\[-1ex]
                    \caption{Auxiliary quantities}
                    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                        Sea-level air density&\rho\textsubscript{ref}=\frac{p\textsubscript{ref}}{RT\textsubscript{ref}}\sim\qty{1,25}{kg.m^{-3}}\\
                        Density scale height&h\textsubscript{sc}=\frac{\gamma p\textsubscript{ref}}{g \rho\textsubscript{ref}}\sim\qty{11}{km}\\
                        Sound speed&c\textsubscript{ref}=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma p\textsubscript{ref}}{\rho\textsubscript{ref}}}\sim\qty{330}{m.s^{-1}}\\
                        Internal wave speed&c\textsubscript{int}=\sqrt{gh\textsubscript{sc}\frac{\triangle\Theta}{T\textsubscript{ref}}}\sim\qty{110}{m.s^{-1}}\\
                        Thermal wind velocity&u\textsubscript{ref}=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{gh_{sc}}{\Omega a}\frac{\triangle\Theta}{T\textsubscript{ref}}\sim\qty{12}{m.s^{-1}}\\
                    \end{tblr}  
%                \end{+array}
            \end{+array}
                \qquad
                \begin{minipage}{0.34\linewidth}
                    \caption{Physically distinguished scales}
                    \vspace{-1ex}
                    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                        Planetary scale&L\textsubscript{p}=\frac{\pi}{2}{a}\sim\qty{10000}{km}\\
                        Obukhov radius&L\textsubscript{Ob}=\frac{c\textsubscript{ref}}{\Omega}\sim\qty{3300}{km}\\
                        Synoptic scale&L\textsubscript{Ro}=\frac{c\textsubscript{int}}{\Omega}\sim\qty{1100}{km}\\
                        Meso-$\beta$ scale&L\textsubscript{Meso}\frac{u\textsubscript{ref}}{\Omega}\sim\qty{150}{km}\\
                        Meso-$\gamma$ scale&h\textsubscript{sc}=\frac{\gamma p\textsubscript{ref}}{g \rho\textsubscript{ref}}\sim\qty{11}{km}\\
                    \end{tblr} 
                \end{minipage}              
        \end{table}
    \end{frame} 
%\end{section}
\end{document}
```

[image]